# Writing to a device hangs, how can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: linux, serial-port, port

I have a teensy 3.6 as /dev/ttyACM0

I noticed that when I used `serial.write()` in python it would hang. I opened the Arduino IDE serial monitor and I can see the output. When I write in the serial monitor anything it immediately hangs and freezes the Arduino IDE.

I tried to isolate the issue by testing the following :

If I do `cat < /dev/ttyACM0` I get the expect output from the teensy. If I keep this open in a terminal and do `echo "who" > /dev/ttyACM0` in another terminal, it also hangs and I don't see any additional output on my previously opened terminal.

Why is the writing blocked and how can I fix this?